# Can't configure apache poi ooxml for maven

Tags: java, excel, maven, apache-poi, sax

Have a need to open both XLS of 2003 format and XLSX of 2007+ format.
Have a code like

```
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create( inputStream );
```

`pom.xml` contains:

- org.apache.poi:poi v3.9
- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml v3.9
- org.apache.poi:ooxml-schemas v1.1

But get the exception with SAX:
`Could not initialize a SAX Parser. Please add a SAX parser to your classpath along with preferably jaxp.jar`
And the exception is thrown in code like

```
SAXReader xmlReader = new SAXReader(); //using dom4j library
xmlReader.read(file);
```

I've found that in my classpath there're two org.xml.sax.XMLReader classes. One in java 1.7 rt.jar, other - in `xml-apis:xml-apis` artifact. And when dom4j is trying to create an XMLReader, it tries to cast it to XMLReader from `xml-apis:xml-apis`, not from rt.jar. And fails.

Hmm, I thought and excluded xml-apis:xml-apis from all implicit dependencies in my pom.xml.
Then - hallelujah - SAXReader works!

But the other exception fails: 
when creating Workbook poi-ooxml goes to ThemesTable.java:44 and executes

```
theme = ThemeDocument.Factory.parse(part.getInputStream());
```

And there java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError is thrown with message "Could not initialize class org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans"

But org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.3.0 is in my result jar!
Sample code that fails:

```
XmlBeans.compilePath( "" );
```

But it works if - what do you think - if `xml-apis:xml-apis` is included in pom.xml!

Help, guys, how to tame apache.poi for ooxml?

Comment: Did you try following the instructions on the [Apache POI Components page](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components)? I have all of the jars from that page on my classpath, and my OOXML code works just fine...

Comment: Sure, @Gagravarr, sure. The trouble is about xml-apis, I think. But where?

Comment: Have you seen how [Apache Tika does it](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tika/trunk/tika-parsers/pom.xml)? That's one way to pull in all of Apache POI via Maven without problems, and there are lots of other examples out there if you google...